# Определить уникального пользователя

Tags: php, laravel

Здравствуйте.
У меня есть таблица clicks, в ней содержится токен посетителя, его ип, ид товара,ид продавца.

```
user_token | ip | product_id | seller_id
```

Все это работает так: посетитель заходит в карточку товара, под карточкой товара есть предложения, посетитель кликает на одно из предложений, записывается его токен, ип, ид товара, и ид предложения. Потом происходит редирект на сайт продавца. Вопрос в том, как определить пользователя, который кликал уже по этому предложению, имея его данные (токен и ип).

Comment: Так получится, что пользователь будит уникальным для всех товаров, а мне надо что бы он был уникальным (тоесть, если он кликнул несколько раз, засчитался только 1 клик), для одного товара. Допустим посетитель кликнул на предложение от продовца "мир холодильников" под товаром "bosch 123". Но если посетитель кликнет на предложение того же продавца под товаром "indesit k321", его клик засчитается но так же только 1 клик.

Comment: Я просто не представляю как. Мне бы  какой нибудь пример бы:)

Comment: Вопрос был как определить, а не как сделать

Comment: Да, вы правы:) буду копать в этом направлении. Спасибо за наводку.

Comment: @tCode Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо записать `user_token` в `$_COOKIE`

При проверке в дальнейшем проверять связку `user_token | ip | product_id`

Так вы сможете отследить уникальные переходы